# How does jetty.security.ConfigurableSpnegoLogin work?

Tags: jetty, kerberos, embedded-jetty, spnego

I'm trying to make a jetty server use kerberos. For this, I found that there is a built-in solution, called **org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService**.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any useful documentation for this. There is one closed [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4982) in the github jetty project about this, but those comments did not help either.

Can someone point me to an example on how to use it? I only need this for authentication, but no authorization.

The way I'd use it is something like this:

```
ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService spnegoLoginService = new ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService(....);
//set up the spnegoLoginService

ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setLoginService(spnegoLoginService);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`SPNEGOAuthenticationTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.7/jetty-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/SPNEGOAuthenticationTest.java#L124-L152) has a server side component example.

```java
server = new Server();
server.setSessionIdManager(new DefaultSessionIdManager(server));
HashLoginService authorizationService = new HashLoginService(realm,
   realmPropsPath.toString());
ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService loginService = 
  new ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService(realm, 
    AuthorizationService.from(authorizationService, ""));
loginService.addBean(authorizationService);
loginService.setKeyTabPath(serviceKeyTabPath);
loginService.setServiceName(serviceName);
loginService.setHostName(serviceHost);
server.addBean(loginService);

ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"**"}); //allow any authenticated user
ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
mapping.setPathSpec("/secure");
mapping.setConstraint(constraint);
securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
authenticator = new ConfigurableSpnegoAuthenticator();
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
securityHandler.setHandler(handler);

SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
sessionHandler.setHandler(securityHandler);
```

To use `ConfigurableSpnegoLoginService` you require (must have / not optional) ...

- A Servlet / HTTP Authentication realm
- A Servlet Authentication role
- A Servlet Constraint + Constraint Mapping
- An AuthorizationService (but you don't want a authorization??)
- A ConfigurableSpnegoAuthenticator

Not entirely sure how you will satisfy the "no authorization" part with spnego/kerberos + http authentication + servlet constraint / authentication in the mix.  Maybe you have to drop the "no authorization" part and define proper authorization / roles, but put everyone in the same role??

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maybe I misunderstood how it works. What I am looking for is to enable kerberos authentication on the embedded jetty server. The authorisation part will be handled by servlet filters. What would be the right approach here?

Comment: Then you are not using Servlet Auth, you'll wind up having to do everything in your Filter.

Comment: So basically if I want Servlet Filter Based authorization, then I cannot use jetty’s Spnego logic to do the authentication part?

Comment: Jetty does Servlet auth (which is authn and authz), you need the whole thing for it to work, you cannot be selective. This means constraints + constraint-mapping + realm + roles + login-config + auth-method + loginservice + authenticator etc.  If I were you, I'd just do authz twice. once with super lax authz in Servlet spec, and then once again in the Filter but more restrictive.  Just be 100% careful with the response 401 rules!